# All abelian groups are top.groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

I think yes, because all abelian groups isomorphic to some quotient group of free group. And we can represent this quitent group like the Cayley graph, and make the standart metric on the set of vertex, were all edges have the lenght $=c$ ($c$ -- some constant in $\mathbb{R}$). And create the metric topology after that.

How right am I? I am not sure, that all abelian groups can represent by Cayley graph...

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh, I am incorrect understand the definition of top.group, sorry

Comment: @DerekHolt But any groups can get the discrete top.?

Comment: Of course any group with the discrete topology is a topological group, in the sense that the operations $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ and $x\mapsto -x$ are continuous, because every map on the group and its product with itself is going to be continuous...because every set is open.

Comment: @Anguepa So I can say, that I can represent any group like a top.group?

Comment: Sure, but it's kind of a trivial statement. 

The idea is that there is something interesting about the topology that makes it a topological group, e.g. manifold topology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any group becomes a topological group when equipped with the **discrete topology** (= all sets are open, and hence all functions from it are continuous). So every group is a topological group, abelian or not (or rather: every group is *the underlying group of* some topological group).

Comment: I am saing about abelian, because I am not sure, that for all non-abelian groups exist connected Cayley graph

Comment: @Arsenii All groups have connected Cayley graphs, abelian or not.

Comment: Where can I read about this? May be you know good textbook?

Comment: @Arsenii Just look at the definition of Cayley graph. Any group element $g$ is given by a word on the generators, and this word defines a path from the identity vertex of the Cayley graph to the vertex corresponding to $g$. So to get from $g$ to $h$ you can just go from $g$ to the identity and then from the identity to $h$.

Comment: Ye, I think, that I had confuse in the point that some non-abelian groups Cayley graphs can be very crazy in theirs structure. Like Heisenberg group

Comment: I am right, that if in Cayley graph exist loop this equivalent that in free group exist some relations?